# jquery replace content remove nested autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

when replacing content of target by similar content newContent:
    `target.html(newContent.html())`
the autocomplete attached to a nested DOM of target does not get completely removed so I cannot reattach a new autocomplete to the corresponding element in newContent.

As in documentation of jquery it should remove all handlers and events, but of parent elemnt only!? how to remove all handlers and events of all nested DOMs (not just first-level children of `target`) as well?

I have similar problems with dialogs.
Neither `.empty()` or `.remove()` seem to work as well

Answer (score 0):

you should probably destroy the dialog/autocomplete first before removing the html

```
$('#myauto').autocomplete('destroy').remove();
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-destroy

Comment: I tried it that way by providing code before `target.html(...)`, but no success at all
    `target.find(".ui-autocomplete-input").each(function(){
      $(this).autocomplete("destroy").remove();
    });`